# How to get base currency in a magento update script?

Tags: magento

I try to get base currency code in an update script, to create some special products.
If I try to use

```
Mage::app()->getStore()->getBaseCurrencyCode();
```

I got 'USD', which is the default default currency.
Looks like stores are not initialized yet.

Comment: You are right, the store configuration at this point is not loaded yet. I don't think it is possible to retrieve this configuration from an update script without using direct DB queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found there is a 'data update' script which is run after init, it's called data-upgrade-versionfrom-versionto.php.

See Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyDataUpdates()

Comment: Nice find! A colleague of mine had the same problem once and had to pull some tricks to solve it, but with data upgrade scripts it would have been way better

Comment: I used many tricks myself, including raw sql inserts, before discovering this